# How to reference Data from PowerQ that can change row

Tags: reference, powerquery

Good Afternoon.

I have a workbook that basically uses power query to take data from the CoinmarketCap Api and displays this to a sheet called "CMC".

I have a second sheet that references data in the CMC sheet. (Seen Below)

[Table referencing CMC sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Umr.png)

For example cell D4 references =CMC!M2+0

This is referencing the Bitcoin row which is row 2 in the "CMC" sheet. If, for example Bitcoin moved to row 3 on the "CMC" sheet then my table would be messed up and replaced with values from the new coin moved to row 2.

Is there anyway to Dynamically reference the data from the "CMC" sheet so that if a coin moves to a different row my table on sheet two can still update accordingly without me having to manually change the row?

[CMC Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxqt5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Load the powerquery result as a pivot table report not a table

Then pull desired data from pivot table with GETPIVOTDATA formula

To enter formula, type = then click on desired cell in pivot. Example output:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Column1.price_usd",pivot_tab!$A$3,"Column1.symbol","XRP")
```

Alternately, leave it in the table, and use vlookup or index/match on the symbol :

```
=vlookup("XRP",table_tab!$a:$f,3,false)
```

similar to

```
=index(table_tab!c:c,match("XRP",table_tab!a:a,0))
```

Comment: Thank you. The Vlookup worked a treat. Thanks for taking the time to respond.